# zend, getting a param that a value of http://

Tags: zend-framework

im trying to get a param from my url.. via `$this->_request->getParam('url')`

so,  /url/http://www.yahoo.com

but the value of param url is h   because theres forward slashes in the value..
how can i get the full url...  as now, its thinking that the http:// is another param..

```
    public function getUrlToGo(){

$url=$this->_request->getParam('url');
if ($url='http://www.yahoo.com'){
return $this->_forward("findyahoo", "urlclass");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when urls are passed in the address bar the slashes (and most other characters) are converted into url-safe characters.

```
<?php
$url = urlencode('http://www.yahoo.com');
echo $url; //http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com
```

You can then use `urldecode($url)` to get the original url back.

Comment: its still treating the first part of the url as simgle values...  e.g. its echoing http%3A